# PHP function in WordPress for admin columns has error in php 8

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8

I'm working on a child theme with custom plugin created by someone else to try to make it work with PHP 8 (it works with 7.3.3 but nothing after). The issue is in the backend list of items in a custom post type. See screenshot https://nimb.ws/Su4Pwr

The problem code appears to be

```
function gs_custom_columns($tax) {
  global $post;
  
  if ( 'production' != $post->post_type )
    return;

  $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,$tax);
  if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ( $terms as $c )
      $out[] = "<a href='edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=language&post_type=production&tag_ID=$c->term_id'> " . esc_html(sanitize_term_field('name', $c->name, $c->term_id, 'post_tag', 'display')) . "</a>";
    echo join( ', ', $out );
  } else {
    _e('No Tags');
  }
}
```

Line 218 referenced in the screenshot is the line

```
$out[] = "<a href='edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=language&post_type=production&tag_ID=$c->term_id'> " . esc_html(sanitize_term_field('name', $c->name, $c->term_id, 'post_tag', 'display')) . "</a>";
```

Is there a different way to do this for PHP8?  Or simply a better way?

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: what is value of `$c`? just use `print_r($c);` inside for loop

Comment: All I can see in the entire file for $c is  

foreach ( $terms as $c )

Comment: I ended up changing the code prior to this that defined the columns which appears to have fixed the backend error.